# I can't create a gap between Navbar and content

Tags: html, css, navbar

I tried to create a "fixed" navigation bar, but the navigation bar overlaps with the content of the website. I have already tried several possibilities, for example with top, margin and padding.

HTML:

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="/pages/about.html">About</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Events</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <div class="animation start-home"></div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

SCSS:

```scss
header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10rem 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;

    nav {
        margin: 27px auto 0 auto;
        width: 590px;
        height: 50px;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 4;

        // background-color: #34495e;
        background-color: #313131;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 0;

        a {
        line-height: 50px;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your header padding nor margin will affect your main content since it's positioned "on-top" of it. You will need to set the padding on your main content instead of the header.

Try something like this: https://codepen.io/s1adem4n/pen/XWoywrb

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="/pages/about.html">About</a>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#">Events</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <div class="animation start-home"></div>
  </nav>
</header>

<p>
Libero qui beatae vitae sed aut non pariatur. Quia adipisci facilis natus asperiores vel. Omnis commodi animi assumenda consequatur quod dignissimos distinctio. Odit recusandae est possimus totam aliquam aut. Reiciendis ad in qui quisquam eveniet minus.
</p>
```

And the CSS:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10rem 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;

  nav {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 590px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;

    // background-color: #34495e;
    background-color: #313131;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;

    a {
      line-height: 50px;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 15px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  width: 50ch;
}
```